# Spring Call REQUIRED method from REQUIRED_NEW method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-transactions

I have bean entry as below

```
<bean id="inspectReqImpl"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="transactionAttributes">
            <props>
                <prop key="activateRequest">PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW</prop>                             
                <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="target">
            <bean
                class="com.test.InspectRequestImpl">                
            </bean>
        </property>
</bean>

<bean id="inspectReqProcess"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="transactionAttributes">
            <props>             
                <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="target">
            <bean
                class="com.test.InspectRequestProcessImpl">             
            </bean>
        </property>
</bean>
```

when I call com.test.InspectRequestImpl.activateRequest() method then Spring will create new transaction

```
public void activateRequest()
{

Calling method of InspectRequestProcessImpl(ex: processRequest())
For InspectRequestProcessImpl we have defined all methods as PROPAGATION_REQUIRED

}
```

So, If any exception (Checked or Unchecked) comes in method `(InspectRequestProcessImpl.processRequest())` for which transaction propagation is `REQUIRED` then what will be effect on `InspectRequestImpl.activateRequest()` which has transaction propagation `REQUIRED_NEW`

- How spring will behave in this case. Will it commit `InspectRequestImpl.activateRequest()` or rollback ?
- Will it just rollback contents of `InspectRequestProcessImpl.processRequest()` or will raise exception ?

Answer (score 2):

The default behaviour is to commit after a checked exception and rollback after an unchecked one.

If you like to do a rollback after checked exceptions, add a rollback rule to your transaction specification.
Use "PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Exception" for generic exceptions or "PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-MyException" for a specific one.

If your method declares that throws the exception, the exception will be thrown, else it won't. Spring doesn't propagates the exception... You can try/catch the exception and do nothing.